# Угодья - от слова "угождать"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Есть понятие "сельскохозяйственные угодья". То есть, совокупность земель, отведенных под сельское хозяйство. Еще бывают охотничьи угодья.
Насколько я знаю, примерно в таком же значении это слово употреблялось и раньше. Но почему именно "угодья"? От слова "угождать"? Или имеется в виду, что они "угодны для посева"? Но тогда правильнее было бы сказать "пригодны".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Угодье - земли, пригодные для с.х. Приставка У часто используется в с.-х. терминах: удой, укос, умолот. Также: гора - угорье (место рядом с горой).

Годный - подходящий, хороший, от годити - удовлетворять, подходить. Родственные слова: год, погода, пригожий. Старшее значение - подходящее время, потом - время вообще.

Угодить - сделать что-то хорошее, подходящее.